# Optimization over permutation -- finding a region that justifies optimal solution

Tags: permutations, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose there is $N$ agents, and each agent is characterized by its attributes $X_i$. Let $X = (X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_N)$. I order agents to maximize an objective function $f(X,\Pi)$, where $\Pi$ is an order of agents living in permutation over of agents $perm(N)$. All I know about the function $f()$ is that it is continuously differentiable they are not concave.

The optimal order $\Pi^*$ will be obtained:
$$\Pi^* = \arg\max_{\Pi \in perm(N)} f(X,\Pi). $$

Now, suppose I know $\Pi^*$, and I want to find all possible value of $X$ that justify the optimal order $\Pi^*$. I wonder if there is a nice way to solve this problem.

For now, I transform the optimization problem into nonlinear programing with linear constraint. Let $Y$ be an $N\times N$ matrix and $R = (1,\cdots,N)'$. Then, my problem becomes
$$\Pi^* = \arg\max_{Y} f(X,YR), $$
subject to
$$\sum_{j}y_{ij} = 1,~\sum_i y_{ij} =1,~\forall i,j, 0\le y_{ij}\le 1,$$
where $y_{ij}$ is the $i$th row and $j$th column element of $Y$. Then, I find a region of $X$ that justify $\Pi^*$ using KKT conditions -- for a given $X$ if there exist Lagrangian multipliers that satisfy KKT conditions.

Comment: Clarification: what do you mean by "find all possible value of X that justify the optimal order $\Pi^*$". Do you mean  find all X for which $\Pi^*$ is the optimal ordering?

Comment: @RahulMadhavan I meant to say: I have a permutation $\Pi^*$, I want to find all $X$ such that $\Pi^* = \arg\max_{\Pi} f(X,\Pi)$.

Comment: This seems to be equivalent to finding the boundary of such $X$. In other words, find all $X$ such that $f(X,\Pi^*) = f(X,\Pi_j)$ for some $\Pi_j$